# Rails relationship with same name as column name`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, conflict

I have a bit of a problem with rails. I have an inherited database (hense the wacky column names) that looks a bit like this:

```
customer
---------
Customer_ID | name | fleet_size | category
1             'bob'     20          60

category
----------
Category_ID | Description
1               'Example Category'
```

So a customer belongs to a category and a category has many customers. The models look like so:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "category"

  has_many :customers, :foreign_key => "category"
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "customer"

  belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => "Category_ID"
end
```

Because of the name of the `category` column in the customers table, I think there might be a conflict which means I can't call `@customer.category.Description` in the view. Any ideas on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can always rename the association:

```
belongs_to :something_else, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "Category_ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the association name and used as

```
belongs_to :cust_category, :foreign_key => "Category_ID", :class => 'Category'

@customer.cust_category.Description
```

May be this will solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That is what I'm looking for, it just returns this: `undefined method Description for nil:NilClass` but I guess that's for another question

Comment: Woops, apparently I forgot the `unless customer.supplier_index.nil?`

Comment: @customer.cust_category.present? is also an option to check. :)

Comment: That looks slightly nicer :) Thanks